# Using sub-queries and joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have got the following statement:

> List of names and addresses from the customers who made purchases in 1997.

So I thought the two following ways were correct but they aren't; why?

```
select contactname, address from customers
       inner join orders
       on customers.customerid = orders.customerid
       where date_part('year', orderdate) = 1997
       order by contactname

select contactname, address from customers
       where customerid in
             (select customerid from orders 
              where date_part('year', orderdate) = 1997)
       order by contactname
```

Comment: What's wrong with the results that you're getting back?  (I would find another way to select the date, though.  Doing a function on a column in a where clause like that is usually a good way to get a table scan.  Maybe where orderdate >= 1/1/1997 and orderdate <= 12/31/1997 or something like that.)

Comment: Because in the first case I have got repeated results, suppose Alexander - Alexander - Alexander - Anabela - Anabela insted the second one gives me Alexander-Anabela-...

Comment: Should I have to add Distinct between select and contact name? I was reading about it and subqueries and joins should be the same, but they are different speaking by performance right?

Comment: If a customer placed N > 0 orders in 1997, they will be listed N times by the first query, but once by the second.  You could use DISTINCT to eliminate the duplicates, though that's a modestly expensive operation.

Comment: Someone recently suggested I use "group by" instead of distinct.  FYi.

Comment: It'll work; I don't see an advantage to GROUP BY when you're not producing aggregates (COUNT, SUM, AVG, etc).

Comment: After googling "group by vs. distinct" I have to agree.  There doesn't seem to be a performance difference of any significance.  I should have googled it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many *correct* ways to do this. An [`EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join is probably the fastest in PostgreSQL, if you just want a list of distinct customers and no further details from the orders other than that at least 1 exists:

```
SELECT c.contactname, c.address
FROM   customers c
WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   orders o 
    WHERE  o.customerid = c.customerid
    AND    o.orderdate >= '1997-1-1'::date
    AND    o.orderdate <  '1998-1-1'::date
    )
ORDER BY contactname;
```

Why use?

```
    WHERE  o.orderdate >= '1997-1-1'::date
    AND    o.orderdate <  '1998-1-1'::date
```

Instead of:

```
    WHERE  date_part('year', orderdate) = 1997
```

With your expression PostgreSQL would have to compute a value for every row before the condition can be checked. In the alternative form, the column (as is) is matched against two constant terms. This can also use an index more easily. Should be faster.

Note also how I use [table aliases](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES) to make the query easier to read.

Your *first* query suffers from multiplication of rows due to the `JOIN`. If a row in table `customer` has multiple matching rows in table `orders` you get one row for each order. You could fix that with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT c.contactname, c.address
FROM   customers c
JOIN   orders o USING (customerid)
WHERE  o.orderdate >= '1997-1-1'::date
AND    o.orderdate <  '1998-1-1'::date
GROUP  BY c.customer_id   --- or whatever is the primary key of c 
ORDER  BY c.contactname
```

.. which is another way to do it. But most probably slower. You would use this form if you also want to retrieve additional (aggregated) data from table `orders` ..

`DISTINCT` would be an alternative to `GROUP BY`, doing mostly the same in this simple case. Remove the `GROUP BY` clause for this and add `DISTINCT` after `SELECT`.

You could also fix your second query with `DISTINCT`, but rather use my first example.

Comment: The EXISTS is not only the fastest (because it is the oldest, and has been recognised by the generators for 20+ years), it is also the clearest (at the expense of a correlated subquery). The IN-variant is often substandard (cause of the removal of duplicates) and dangerous (causes by the 3val logic), and the LEFT JOIN... WHERE NULL is a contra-intuitive ugly beast. IMNSVHO

Comment: @wildplasser. True and insightful, except for your last example. `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE NULL` would be for the *opposite* query: "Find customers *without* orders". Not applicable here. I posted a [**comparison of the three methods** on dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16651/3684) recently (also with `LEFT JOIN .. col IS NULL`).

Comment: Oops, you're right of course. The point is: I detest the construct so much that I can't even remember it. It is a non-existant construct ;-) *seeks medication*

Comment: @wildplasser: I would hate starting a non-relevant discussion but can't help just asking: aren't you being a tiny little bit too much extra-over-prejudiced against LEFT JOIN ... WHERE NULL? While "contra-intuitive" *may* be a valid point, "ugly" is just plain and simple subjective and I beg to object!